# ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET MVC 4 razor syntax changes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created two application in VS2012

1. Application#1. **MVC 3**, NET 4.5
2. Application#2. **MVC 4**, NET 4.5

Now I open any .cshtml file and add the following code:

```
<div>
@if (true)
{
      @string.Format("{0}", "test")
}
</div>
```

It works just fine in Application#1 (mvc3) and I see "test" word displayed. But it doesn't work in Application#2 (mvc4).

Could anybody explain why it happens and what should be changed?

**UPDATE:** I've just found out one more very weird thing. If you replace @string.format("some text") with @String.format("some text") everything works fine (note uppercase String)

Comment: Are you sure `Model` is still `null` in your second test?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. See the updated code (I replaced it with "true")

Comment: Please try my updated answer with <p>@string.Format("{0}", "test")</p> and it should work... ;) + 1 For sure ;)

Comment: Basically without HTML place holder where the TEST would display on broswer??? Browser understand HTML TAG which is missing here...

Comment: Jigar, thanks for reply. But I don't want <p> to be rendered. <text> is better solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had a similar issue when upgrading... it appears that simply writing `@string.Format("{0}", "test")` will no longer write directly onto the page as it did in MVC3. You instead have to do something like this:

```
<div>
@if (true)
{
      Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}", "test"));
}
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
@if (true)
{
      <text>@string.Format("{0}", "test"))</text> //added @ to evaluate the expression instead of treating as string literal
}
</div>
```

Comment: I've just found out one more very weird thing. If you replace @string.format("some text") with @String.format("some text") everything works fine (note uppercase String)

Comment: BTW, Html.Raw won't encode text. <text>...</text> solution is better  one

Comment: I'll have to test that string casing that you mentioned. That would really be absurd if that made a difference.

I showed both examples of emitting raw HTML and encoded HTML intentionally. Html.Raw may be a viable solution. For me, there are cases where I want to emit raw HTML. But obviously that depends on your application and scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Razor engine?

Since you are in a `@if` block you could write: `string.Format("{0}", "test")` rather than     `@string.Format("{0}", "test")`.

*Note the @*

Comment: It does not compile. It requires ; at the end. But once added, it does not render "test" string in output HTML

Answer (score 0):

In Razor Syntax for Conditional check you can start a block with one @ sign and then put your Condition inside..

E.g

```
  @{var price=20;}
<html>
<body>
@if (price>30)
  {
  <p>The price is too high.</p>
  }
else
  {
  <p>The price is OK.</p>
  }
</body>
</html>
```

So in your case you are using two @ within one block. Check that part and it will be resolved.

So your code block should look like following.

```
<div>
@if (Model == null)
{
      <p>@string.Format("{0}", "test")</p>
}
</div>
```

On top of that if you put "@" two time like it is there in your code lines it will give you hint as image below. This is feature of Razor Syntax 4.0. Also you miss the ";" in you code line.

[image]

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_cs_logic.asp

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your code compiles (string.Format("{0}", "test");), but it does not render "test" string. How should it be rendered now? And why did it work fine in MVC3?